# How do I embed a flash SWF file and get around the IE security layer without using swfobject (to keep down file size)

Tags: javascript, flash, embedded-resource, swfobject, embedding

I'm looking for a way to embed an SWF into a page and get around the Internet Explorer security issue (where it requires an extra click to "activate" the flash file).

I've got my code working with swfobject, but I'm using this in an embedded widget context (eg a clickable banner ad) so I am really trying to keep my file size down, and swfobject adds about 10k worth of minified Javascript that just feels like more than I need

I just need basic flash rendering, I'm not really that worried about Flash version detection (I'm using an old enough version of Flash for the SWF) though a fallback solution if flash is not available would be nice.

Finally, this has to be something that can work entirely from a single Javascript file included somewhere in the BODY tag of the containing page. (The reason I say this is because I had some issues even with the swfobject version when I was document.write'ing a SCRIPT tag for the swfobject.js into the BODY of the page instead of the HEAD).

I hope that makes sense, I can clarify if needed.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

"Click to activate" is no longer an issue, [**see this note**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb969055.aspx).

Comment: I had seen that, but in my test browsers (IE 6.0 and 7.0) it still seems to be an issue. Did they patch even older versions? I'm hesitant to update my browsers (they run in separate VMs), as I don't want to end up with IE8 or something. I'm a Microsoft nuby for sure

Comment: I am pretty sure this was an issue with just IE7. But in short the solution was to script to the creation of the embed tags via JavaScript.